Highcharts Dashboard Add Component does not work properly
Due to some requirements my team has for a project, I'm playing around with Highcharts Dashboard.
One must-have feature for us is to be able to customize the dashboard by adding, removing or modifying the charts/components. Unfortunately the "Add component" features apparently does not work properly, I'm not sure if I am missing something of if the feature is actually a bit buggy.
I tried it both on the app we are working on and on the JFiddle example provided by the highcharts documentation ([https://www.highcharts.com/docs/dashboards/edit-mode](Edit mode documentation) -> "Edit mode live example") and both time I got the same error (Stacktrace). This happens both on Chrome and Firefox developer edition.
What I've done (aka, how to try to reproduce it):
I clicked on the hamburger on top right corner, switched on the edit mode, clicked "Add component" and tried to do a drag and drop of an highchart item from the sidebar into the dashboard.
I expected the new chart to be added in the dashboard, but instead the sidebar closed with no changes in the dashboard. In the browser console I saw the above mentioned error about the "getType" of the undefined "t" object.
Does anyone already experienced something similar or have some suggestions about this issue?
Thanks!
UPDATE - BUG IDENTIFIED BY HIGHCHARTS DEVS - https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=193004#p193004
